# Metric spaces and the Distance between a Point and a Set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have a long problem I am currently working on and I'm not sure I know what direction to take.

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A \subseteq X$. For $x \in X$, define $d(A,x) = \inf \{d(a,x) : a\in A \}.$

1. Given $x \in X$, construct a sequence $(a_n)$ in $A$ such that
   $lim_{n→∞} ⁡d(a_n,x) = d(A,x)$.
2. Prove that for every $x \in X$, $d(A,x) = d(\overline{A},x)$.
3. Let $f:X→[0,\infty)$ defined by $f(x) = d(A,x)$. Prove that $f$
   is continuous.
4. Let $x \notin \overline{A}$, prove that there are disjoint open sets
   $U_1$ and $U_2$ such that $\overline {A} \subseteq U_1$ and $x \in U_2$.

For the first one, because of the sequence lemma, I am guaranteed that there exists such a sequence. If I let $L = d(A,x)$, and $\epsilon >0$, then we can construct it in this manner. For $n \in \mathbb {N}$, and $c_n \in A$, let $a_n = d(c_n, x)$ such that $a_n > a_{n+1}$.Taking $N > 1/\epsilon$, for $n > N$, $a_n \in V(L, \epsilon)$.

I'm not sure how to work out the rest.

Comment: The $a_n$ you've taken is a real number, but it need to be in $A$.

Answer (score 1):

As far as number $2$, any sequence in $A$ is also a sequence in $\overline{A}$, so it's clear that $d(A,x)\geq d(\overline{A},x)$. On the other hand, let $y\in\overline{A}$. Then $y$ is a limit of a sequence $x_n\in A$, so $d(y,x)\geq d(A,x)$, and therefore $d(\overline{A},x)\geq d(A,x)$.

For $3$, it is sufficient to check that preimages of open intervals are open sets. Consider the interval $I=(a,b)$, and let $x\in f^{-1}(I)$. Then we need to show there is an open neighborhood of $x$ contained in $f^{-1}(I)$. Take $\epsilon=\frac12\min\{d(A,x)-a,b-d(A,x)\}$. Then the $\epsilon$ ball around $x$ should work, thanks to the triangle inequality.

Finally, for $4$, we can use $3$. If $x\not\in\overline{A}$, then $d(A,x)=\epsilon>0$. Then we can take $U_1=f^{-1}([0,\frac{\epsilon}{3}))$ and $U_2=f^{-1}((\frac{2\epsilon}{3},\infty))$. By the continuity of $f$, those sets are open.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Tony, but I don't see why it is clear that $d(A,x) \ge d(\overline{A},x)$?

Comment: If $A\subset B$, then $\inf(A)\geq \inf(B)$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, since $A \subseteq \overline{A}$, then $d(A,x) \ge d(\overline{A},x)$ since $\inf \{d(a,x) \mid a \in A \} \ge \inf \{d(a,x) \mid a \in \overline{A} \}$ .

Comment: ...and that's different from what I've just said, how? It's more explicitly spelled out?

Comment: It's actually just the same thing. I'm just clarifying things for James.

Comment: Oh, I see. The way you led of with "Actually" made it seem like you were correcting something. My bad.

Comment: No worries. :) I wish I could update it so it reads better.